# Error C2085:'int_fast63_t': not in formal parameter list

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, macros, compiler-warnings

I have the following code that throws *error C2085:'int_fast63_t': not in formal parameter list*

```
#define       __LEAST64__     __LONG
#define       __FAST64__      __LEAST64__
#ifndef         __FAST63__
#define       __FAST63__      __FAST64__
#endif

typedef signed   __TYPE(__FAST63__)     int_fast63_t;
```

I get my error due to the last line `typedef signed   __TYPE(__FAST63__)     int_fast63_t;`

Any leads on how to resolve the error? Also can someone guess how __LONG could have been defined. I don't find it's definition since it's a predefined macro for a Tasking tricore compiler.

Comment: it may be worth mentioning which compiler you're using here ...

Comment: @draghost It's a TASKING tricore compiler

Comment: I suggest you try to run the preprocessor alone on your code to see exactly how that code that blows up looks like. But I'm not familiar with this toolchain of yours so I can't give you any hints on how to do that ...

Comment: What's a 63 bit signed 2's complement integer for anyway? What kind of exotic system is that?

Comment: Are you sure you're actually using the TriCore compiler and not (unintentionally) [Microsoft's compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2085?view=vs-2019)?